# GMB API Insights Invalid JSON Payload received

Tags: google-apps-script, google-my-business-api

I am trying to get some insights of our locations using Google Apps Script and the Google My Business Api.

Getting Reviews and stuff was no big deal.

**The code worked out well in the OAuth2 Playground.**

Here is the request:

```
var myBusinessService = getMyBusinessService();

var payload ={
  "locationNames":["accounts/116447162401331885225/locations/10722475831894877870"],
  "basicRequest": {
    "metricRequests": [{
      "metric": "ALL"
    }],
    "timeRange": {
      "startTime": "2017-01-01T00:00:01.045123456Z",
      "endTime": "2017-01-31T23:59:59.045123476Z"
    }
  }
};

var options = {
  "headers":{
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + myBusinessService.getAccessToken()
  },
  "method": "POST",
  "payload": payload,
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/116447162401331885225/locations:reportInsights', options);
```

The response:

```
{error={code=400, details=[Ljava.lang.Object;@3116fd89, message=Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "basicRequest": Cannot bind query parameter. 'basicRequest' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types., status=INVALID_ARGUMENT}}
```

Hope someone might help me with this.

Regards

Thies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending `payload` as a JavaScript object. As per the error message ("message=Invalid JSON payload received."), you need to send it as JSON. Use `JSON.stringify()` to make `payload` a JSON string.

```
var options = {
  "headers":{
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + myBusinessService.getAccessToken()
  },
  "method": "POST",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
```

Comment: Added the JSON.stringify, but still getting this response:
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"locationNames\":[\"accounts ....

Comment: @ThiesBoysen Also ensure the "Content-Type" header included and set to "application/json"

Comment: @ZanGOlie and Diego With both of your solution proposals it worked out! Many thanks